# Extract row or column from a 2D array to a 2D array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector, fortran

in matlab I am used to write something like this

```
A = [1,2;3,4]    
B = A(:,1)
```

So I extract the first column of matrix A and store it in matrix B, which is  just a vector or a 2x1 Matrix.  However I can't do this in Fortran, since it regards `A(:,1)` as an one dimensional array and thus gives me an error if I want to assign this to a "matrix" B of size 2x1. 
This is an minimal example in Fortran:

```
program test
    implicit none
    double complex, dimension(:,:), allocatable ::  A, B

    allocate(A(2,2), B(2,1))
    A = transpose(reshape((/ 1, 2, 3, 4/), shape(A)))
    B = A(:,1) !gives error that shape mismatch
end program test
```

Since I don't want to treat vectors separately in my algorithm, how can I achieve Matlab like behaviour?

Comment: Thank you all for the help. Unfortunately I couldn't find the old post. However I will upvote the anwser there too ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
B = A(:, 1:1)
```

Or you should also be able to do this:

```
B(:,1) = A(:,1)
```

Either should work.